# Unknown Int 21 parameter

Tags: assembly, x86, dos, interrupt

Right before a `int 21` call I saw `XOR AX, 21CD`, and was just curious what it does. I couldn't find this type of parameter call on the wiki here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MS-DOS_API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to know what was in the register before the XOR instruction, as this just flips the bits at the 1's:

```
0010 0001 1100 1101
```

If the register originally contained zero, then this invokes function 21, which is random read.  The AL register would be set to CD by the same instruction.  This is a puzzle, because the AL register is not used for anything by this call in the documentation I can find.

Comment: Does the paramter call only get stored in the ah register?

Comment: Your right i was misunderstanding where the paramter was comming from